# Python: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: when directory does exist

Tags: python, os.walk

I am trying to create a script that looks through directories and if its called trash and older than 3 months it can be deleted.

So far i have this code.

```
import os, sys, time
from subprocess import call
import path 



now = time.time()
cutoff = now - (30)#(91 * 86400)

path = '/users/shoot_station_5/documents/folderfordeletetest/'

for root, d_names, f_names in os.walk(path):
    print (root, d_names, f_names)
    for _dir in d_names:
        if time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(_dir)) < cutoff:
            print (_dir)
```

When i print the (root, d_names, f_names) it gives me this result

```
/users/shoot_station_5/documents/folderfordeletetest/ ['dont_delete', 'dont_delete_me'] ['.DS_Store']
/users/shoot_station_5/documents/folderfordeletetest/dont_delete ['trash'] ['.DS_Store']
/users/shoot_station_5/documents/folderfordeletetest/dont_delete/trash [] []
/users/shoot_station_5/documents/folderfordeletetest/dont_delete_me ['trash'] ['.DS_Store']
/users/shoot_station_5/documents/folderfordeletetest/dont_delete_me/trash [] []
```

When the last section is run i am getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shoot_station_5/Documents/scripts/walkdelete.py", line 16, in <module>
    if time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(_dir)) < cutoff:
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/genericpath.py", line 55, in getmtime
    return os.stat(filename).st_mtime
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dont_delete'
```

I am trying to have the folders called trash removed as its older than 30 seconds(using that for testing purposes, actually want it to be 3 months) how come i am getting the no such file or directory  error ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.path.join(root, _dir)`

**Ex:**

```
import os, sys, time
from subprocess import call
import path 

now = time.time()
cutoff = now - (30)#(91 * 86400)

path = '/users/shoot_station_5/documents/folderfordeletetest/'

for root, d_names, f_names in os.walk(path):
    print (root, d_names, f_names)
    for _dir in d_names:
        if time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(root, _dir))) < cutoff:
            print (_dir)
```

Comment: now the error is  TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use `absolute path` unless your terminal is in that directory.

Do this instead:

```
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\rajat.prakash\Downloads")
fresh = max(latest_file, key = os.path.getctime)
print(fresh)
```

It will print the latest downloaded Excel report, but first change the directory.